# JavaScript: Add Event Listeners to Dynamic Form Where Specific Form Elements Don't Exist on Page Load?

Tags: javascript, events

I'm curious if there is a way to add event listeners to form fields which are dynamic and not present at page load? My issue is I'm working with a form which is dynamic and changes based on selections made. The issue is, I need to attach event listeners to specific fields in the form but on page load, not all these form elements exist? For example, the dropdown below will always exist on the page:

```
`var employmentStatusSelect = document.getElementById('mainForm:cont_appRequestStatus');
employmentStatusSelect.addEventListener('change',trackEmploymentStatusSelect);`
```

but the next field will show if there is a specific selection from above element

```
var startCurrentJobInput = document.getElementById('mainForm:cont_appRequeststart_job');

startCurrentJobInput.addEventListener('blur', trackStartCurrentJobInput);
```

Since it doesn't exist when the page loads, I can't attach an event listener to it and the above code throws an error. Is there any way to attach the event listener to the 2nd element once it appears? JavaScript only, please! *** I cannot make changes to the form or page and can only inject my code via a Tag Management system ***

Comment: How about the $( document ).ready event?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to post too much code as I thought it might be a distraction!?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update a better way. Turn out if you add a blur event listener to form, all input element will trigger that event too. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur

```js
var form = document.getElementById('mainForm');

form.addEventListener('blur', function( event ) {   
    if(event.target.matches('#cont_appRequeststart_job')){
      console.log('blur event triggered');
    }
}, true);

// add input
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.id = 'cont_appRequeststart_job';
form.appendChild(input)
```

```html
<form id="mainForm">
    
</form>
```

You can keep trying every 0.5s until the element exists. Not recommended.

```
function tryBindEvent(){
    var startCurrentJobInput = document.getElementById('mainForm:cont_appRequeststart_job');
    if(startCurrentJobInput){
        startCurrentJobInput.addEventListener('blur', trackStartCurrentJobInput);
    }else{
        setTimeout(tryBindEvent, 500);
    }   
}
tryBindEvent();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you share more codes, you may get better help. But, I guess what you should do is to run a function (I will call it `assign()` for now) to assign a value to `startCurrentJobInput` when `employmentStatusSelect` has a value.

So, I recommend you to define `startCurrentJobInput` variable globally like this (I guess you would need it globally to use in other funcs):

`var startCurrentJobInput;`

And do not add event listener yet. Then, when `employmentStatusSelect` is selected and new form element created, run `assign` func to assign  `document.getElementById('mainForm:cont_appRequeststart_job')` to `startCurrentJobInput`. Then, you can add event listener to it with:

`startCurrentJobInput.addEventListener('blur', trackStartCurrentJobInput);`

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a event listener on the document body and check the element type inside the callback and do the modifications.

```
document.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    if(e.target && e.target.id === 'mainForm:cont_appRequeststart_job') {
        //do something
    }
});
```